# Mapping with automapper to an object with one additional field results in exception

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I am using autommapper for maping beetween objects and I have one case where I have to maping to an objec that contains one more property then it's source.WHeren I try to run the program I get this error:

> {"\nUnmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type\n===============================================================================================================\r\nGetUpcomingLessons_Result -> UpcomingLessonDTO (Destination member list)\r\neConnect.Model.GetUpcomingLessons_Result -> eConnect.DomainServices.Contracts.DTOs.Dashboard.UpcomingLessonDTO (Destination member list)\r\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nTeacherOfficialName\r\n"}

But what this error is saying can not be true because I added the mapping for this two objects:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>();
```

And the error only accures when I add the additional field TeacherOfficialName.

This is the code from witch I am trying to map:

```
public partial class GetUpcomingLessons_Result
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModuleInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentInstanceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLastName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherGender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LessonNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code to witch I am trying to map:

```
public class UpcomingLessonDTO
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int? ModuleInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentInstanceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLastName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherGender { get; set; }
    public int? LessonNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    // additional fields
    public string TeacherOfficialName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create the mapping for this two objects with automapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Thanks , if I would want for example to add a value to TeacherOfficialName how would I proceed in doing it?

Comment: You can either assign the value yourself after the call to Map, or you can configure AutoMapper to supply the value using projection: see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection for examples.